# Minesweeper game loads very slowly from the Start Menu

Tags: java, performance, beginner, minesweeper

I'm quite a beginner with Java and just this month started learning about GUI and `JFrame` so naturally the first thing I wanted to do was build a Minesweeper Game. Apparently that's a common thing for beginners. However, I may have bitten off more than I can chew.

The game works fine and all, but when you click the Start button, it take a long time to close the Start Menu Panel and show the Main Game Panel. It seems to take longer if I pick Medium difficulty, and even longer if I pick Hard difficulty so I think the problem is the section where I'm drawing all the buttons. Easy mode is a grid of 10x10 buttons, Medium is 15x15, and Hard is 25x25. If someone knows what I can do differently, I'd appreciate it. It's kinda long, but I tried to comment as best I could.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class MineSweeper extends JFrame{

   //OPTIONS
   private int width = 650;
   private int height = 650;
   private int sides = 10;
   private int mines = 10;
   private int time = 0;

   //GAME
   private JPanel gamePanel;  //main board
   private Cell[][] cell;     //cells to click
   private int remainingBombs; //how many bombs are remaining
   private int timePassed;  //how much time is remaining

   //LABELS

   //START PANEL
   private JPanel startPanel;
   private JRadioButton easyButton;
   private JRadioButton mediumButton;
   private JRadioButton hardButton;
   private ButtonGroup optionsGroup;
   private JButton startButton;

   //PROGRESS BAR
   private JPanel progressPanel;
   private JLabel bombsLeftLabel;
   private JTextField bombsLeftText;
   private JLabel timeLeftLabel;
   private JTextField timeLeftText;

   //MENU BAR
   private JMenuBar menuBar;
   private JMenu fileMenu;
   private JMenu optionsMenu;
   private JRadioButtonMenuItem easy;
   private JRadioButtonMenuItem medium;
   private JRadioButtonMenuItem hard;

   public MineSweeper(){

      setTitle("Minesweeper");
      setSize(width, height);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      //MENU BAR
      menuBar = new JMenuBar();

      createFile();
      createOptions();

      menuBar.add(fileMenu);
      menuBar.add(optionsMenu);

      setJMenuBar(menuBar);

      //BUILD START PANEL
      buildStartPanel();   

      //ASSEMBLE
      add(startPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      //VISIBLE
      setVisible(true);

   }

   //CREATE THE FILE MENU
   public void createFile(){

      JMenuItem item;   
      fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
      fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);

      item = new JMenuItem("New");
      item.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
      item.addActionListener(new MenuListener());
      fileMenu.add(item);      

      item = new JMenuItem("Pause");
      item.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_P);
      fileMenu.add(item);

      item = new JMenuItem("Unpause");
      item.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_U);
      fileMenu.add(item);

      item = new JMenuItem("Exit");
      item.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_X);
      item.addActionListener(new MenuListener());
      fileMenu.add(item);

   }

   //CREATE THE OPTIONS MENU
   public void createOptions(){

      JMenuItem item;
      optionsMenu = new JMenu("Options");      
      optionsGroup = new ButtonGroup();     

      item = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Easy", true);
      optionsMenu.add(item);
      optionsGroup.add(item);

      item = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Medium");
      optionsMenu.add(item);
      optionsGroup.add(item);      

      item = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Hard");
      optionsMenu.add(item);
      optionsGroup.add(item);   
   }

   //START PANEL
   public void buildStartPanel(){

      //INITIALIZE
      startPanel = new JPanel();
      easyButton = new JRadioButton("Easy", true);
      mediumButton = new JRadioButton("Medium");
      hardButton = new JRadioButton("Hard");
      optionsGroup = new ButtonGroup();
      startButton = new JButton("Start");

      //LISTENERS
      easyButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
      mediumButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
      hardButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
      startButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

      //LINK OPTIONS GROUP
      optionsGroup.add(easyButton);
      optionsGroup.add(mediumButton);
      optionsGroup.add(hardButton);

      //ADD EVERYTHING TO THE PANEL
      startPanel.add(easyButton);
      startPanel.add(mediumButton);
      startPanel.add(hardButton);
      startPanel.add(startButton);
   }

   //PROGRESS BAR
   public void buildProgressPanel(){

      //INITIALIZE
      progressPanel = new JPanel();
      bombsLeftLabel = new JLabel("Remaining Mines: ");
      bombsLeftText = new JTextField(2);
      bombsLeftText.setEditable(false);
      timeLeftLabel = new JLabel("Time remaining: ");
      timeLeftText = new JTextField(4);
      timeLeftText.setEditable(false);

      progressPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
      progressPanel.add(bombsLeftLabel);
      progressPanel.add(bombsLeftText);
      progressPanel.add(timeLeftLabel);
      progressPanel.add(timeLeftText);

      //SET REMAINING BOMBS/TIME
      remainingBombs = mines;
      bombsLeftText.setText(String.valueOf(remainingBombs));
      timePassed = time;
      timeLeftText.setText(String.valueOf(timePassed));
   }

   //MAIN GAME PANEL
   public void buildGamePanel(){

      //INITIALIZE
      gamePanel = new JPanel();
      gamePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(sides, sides));
      cell = new Cell[sides][sides];

      //DRAW AND ADD CELLS TO CLICK
      for (int i = 0; i < sides; i++){
         for (int j = 0; j < sides; j++){
            cell[i][j] = new Cell();
            gamePanel.add(cell[i][j].getButton());
         }
      }

      //PLANT THE MINES!
      plantMines(); 
      setValue(); 

   }

   //PLANT THE MINES
   public void plantMines(){
      int rand_x;
      int rand_y;
      int plantedMine = 0;

      while(plantedMine < mines){
         //random x,y coords for planting
         rand_x = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((sides - 0)));
         rand_y = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((sides - 0)));

         //make sure there isn't already a bomb there
         if (cell[rand_x][rand_y].getMineValue() != -1){ 
            cell[rand_x][rand_y].setMineValue(-1);
            plantedMine++;
         } 
      }
   }

   //CHECK SURROUNDING CELLS
   public void checkForZero(){
      for (int i = 0; i < sides; i++){
         for (int j = 0; j < sides; j++){
            if (cell[i][j].getIsActive() == true){

               //N
               if (i > 0 && !cell[i-1][j].getIsActive()){
                  cell[i-1][j].checkMineValue();
               }
               //NW
               if (i > 0 && j < sides - 1 && !cell[i-1][j+1].getIsActive()){
                  cell[i-1][j+1].checkMineValue();
               }
               //W
               if (j < sides - 1 && !cell[i][j+1].getIsActive()){
                  cell[i][j+1].checkMineValue();
               }
               //SW
               if (i < sides - 1 && j < sides - 1 && !cell[i+1][j+1].getIsActive()){
                  cell[i+1][j+1].checkMineValue();
               }
               //S
               if (i < sides - 1 && !cell[i+1][j].getIsActive()){
                  cell[i+1][j].checkMineValue();
               }
               //SE
               if (i < sides - 1 && j > 0 && !cell[i+1][j-1].getIsActive()){
                  cell[i+1][j-1].checkMineValue();
               }
               //E
               if (j > 0 && !cell[i][j-1].getIsActive()){
                  cell[i][j-1].checkMineValue();
               }

            }
         }
      }
   }

   //SET VALUE OF THE CELLS
   public void setValue(){
      for (int i = 0; i < sides; i++){
         for (int j = 0; j < sides; j++){
            //if the cell we are checking is not a bomb
            if (cell[i][j].getMineValue() != -1){
               //NE
               if (i > 0 && j > 0 && cell[i-1][j-1].getMineValue() == -1){
                  cell[i][j].setMineValue(cell[i][j].getMineValue()+1);
               }
               //N
               if (i > 0 && cell[i-1][j].getMineValue() == -1){
                  cell[i][j].setMineValue(cell[i][j].getMineValue()+1);
               }
               //NW
               if (i > 0 && j < sides - 1 && cell[i-1][j+1].getMineValue() == -1){
                  cell[i][j].setMineValue(cell[i][j].getMineValue()+1);
               }
               //W
               if (j < sides - 1 && cell[i][j+1].getMineValue() == -1){
                  cell[i][j].setMineValue(cell[i][j].getMineValue()+1);
               }
               //SW
               if (i < sides - 1 && j < sides - 1 && cell[i+1][j+1].getMineValue() == -1){
                  cell[i][j].setMineValue(cell[i][j].getMineValue()+1);
               }
               //S
               if (i < sides - 1 && cell[i+1][j].getMineValue() == -1){
                  cell[i][j].setMineValue(cell[i][j].getMineValue()+1);
               }
               //SE
               if (i < sides - 1 && j > 0 && cell[i+1][j-1].getMineValue() == -1){
                  cell[i][j].setMineValue(cell[i][j].getMineValue()+1);
               }
               //E
               if (j > 0 && cell[i][j-1].getMineValue() == -1){
                  cell[i][j].setMineValue(cell[i][j].getMineValue()+1);
               }            
            }
         }
      }
   }

   //START OPTIONS
   private class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener{
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

         if (e.getSource() == easyButton){
            mines = 10;
            sides = 10;
         }else if (e.getSource() == mediumButton){
            mines = 30;
            sides = 15;
         }else if (e.getSource() == hardButton){
            mines = 99;
            sides = 25;
         }
      }
   }

   //MENU BAR LISTENER
   private class MenuListener implements ActionListener{

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

         String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();

         switch(actionCommand){
            case "New":
               if (!startPanel.isVisible()){
                  gamePanel.setVisible(false);
                  progressPanel.setVisible(false);
                  startPanel.setVisible(true);    
               }        
            break;

            case "Exit":

               System.exit(0);
            break;
         }
      }
   }

   //START GAME
   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

         if (e.getActionCommand() == "Start"){

            //leave start menu
            startPanel.setVisible(false);

            //build panels
            buildProgressPanel();
            buildGamePanel();

            //add to main panel
            add(progressPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);  
         }
      }
   }

   //CLASS FOR EACH INDIVDUAL CELL
   public class Cell extends JFrame{
      private MineSweeper board;

      private JButton button;  //cell

      private JPanel buttonPanel;   //panel for the call

      private ImageIcon covered;
      private ImageIcon mine;
      private ImageIcon flag;
      private ImageIcon one;
      private ImageIcon two;
      private ImageIcon three;
      private ImageIcon four;
      private ImageIcon five;
      private ImageIcon six;
      private ImageIcon seven;
      private ImageIcon eight;

      private int mineValue; //-1 for bomb, 0 for empty cell, 1-8 for how many bombs the cell is touching
      private boolean isActive; //for checking cascading uncover
      private boolean isUncovered; //if we've left-clicked on the cell
      private boolean flagPlanted; //if we've right-clicked on the cell

      public Cell(){   
         setLayout(new BorderLayout());

         //ADD THE IMAGES
         covered = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("covered.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(35,35,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
         mine = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("mine.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(35,35,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
         flag = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("flag.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(35,35,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
         one = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("one.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(35,35,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
         two = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("two.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(35,35,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
         three = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("three.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(35,35,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
         four = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("four.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(35,35,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
         five = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("five.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(35,35,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
         six = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("six.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(35,35,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
         seven = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("seven.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(35,35,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
         eight = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("eight.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(35,35,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));

         //CREATE BUTTON
         button = new JButton("");
         //SET ICON
         button.setIcon(covered);
         //LISTENER FOR MOUSE CLICKS
         button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter());
         //ADD TO PANEL
         add(button);
      }

      //GETTERS/SETTERS          
      public JButton getButton(){ return button; }      
      public int getMineValue(){ return mineValue; }
      public boolean getIsActive(){ return isActive; }  
      public void setMineValue(int mv){ this.mineValue = mv; }

      //CHECK VALUE OF THE CELL
      public void checkMineValue(){
         //bomb
         if (mineValue == -1){
            isUncovered = true;
            button.setIcon(null);
            button.setIcon(mine);
            System.out.print("You Lose");
         }
         //no bomb nearby
         if (mineValue == 0){
            isActive = true;
            isUncovered = true;
            checkForZero();
            button.setVisible(false);
         }
         //bomb nearby
         if (mineValue > 0){
            isUncovered = true;
            button.setIcon(null);
            if (mineValue == 1){ button.setIcon(one);}
            if (mineValue == 2){ button.setIcon(two);}
            if (mineValue == 3){ button.setIcon(three);}
            if (mineValue == 4){ button.setIcon(four);}
            if (mineValue == 5){ button.setIcon(five);}
            if (mineValue == 6){ button.setIcon(six);}
            if (mineValue == 7){ button.setIcon(seven);}
            if (mineValue == 8){ button.setIcon(eight);}
         }
      }

      //PLANT THE FLAG 
      public void plantFlag(){

         flagPlanted = true;
         isUncovered = true;
         //update progress
         remainingBombs -= 1;
         bombsLeftText.setText(String.valueOf(remainingBombs));
         //update icon
         button.setIcon(null);
         button.setIcon(flag);
         //check if done
         if (checkDone()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over");
         }
      }

      //UNPLANT THE FLAG
      public void unplantFlag(){

         flagPlanted = false;
         isUncovered = false;
         //update progress
         remainingBombs += 1;
         bombsLeftText.setText(String.valueOf(remainingBombs));
         //update icon
         button.setIcon(null);
         button.setIcon(covered);
      }

      //CHECK IF WE'RE FINISHED
      public boolean checkDone(){

         for (int i = 0; i < sides; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < sides; j++){
               if (!cell[i][j].isUncovered){
                  return false;
               }
            }
         }
         return true;

      }

      //LISTENER FOR CLICKING THE CELL
      private class MouseAdapter implements MouseListener{

         private boolean pressed;

         //MOUSE PRESSED
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            pressed = true;
         }

         //MOUSE CLICKED
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){ 

            if (pressed){
               if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)){
                  checkMineValue();
               }else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)){
                  if (!isUncovered && !flagPlanted){
                     plantFlag();
                  }else if (isUncovered && flagPlanted){
                     unplantFlag();
                  }
               }
            }
            //HAVE WE CHECKED ALL THE CELLS?
            if (checkDone()){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over");
            }
         }

         public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
         public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
         public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}

      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      new MineSweeper();
   }
}
```

Comment: Before guessing, you should take some measurements, e.g. by simply building the difference between two `System.currentTimeMillis()` calls at the start and end of an operation. Not heeding my own advice here: I *guess* that the time lag is due to your loading of the icons in the constructor of *every* cell. You should probably load these once, and simply reference the icons you loaded.

Comment: @mtj Good guess! Such a simple fix that I couldn't see. I was looking at it as the cell class being built once and then being referenced multiple times, but I appear to have been wrong.